# <lightning-tree> LWC Adding each section a dynamic color

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I am working on  and we got a requirement to have different color for each section dynamically based on the data available for each section.

I have tried with template.queryselector() to get section, but not able to add CSS property to those sections.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible with the out-of-the-box lightning-tree component of Salesforce. [The documentation itself](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree/specification) doesn't provide such a facility, and it is impossible to manipulate the layout of web components from the embedding markup. (Don't waste your time on `template.queryselector()`. You can read about web components and shadow DOM [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM).) Even if you had styling hooks for colours ([the documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/trees/) - which is often incomplete in this respect - lists only a single one), you'd be unable to differentiate depending on data.

However, Salesforce provides the source code [here](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes?tab=readme-ov-file#documentation). If it is worth the effort, grab it and make your multi-color tree grid 100% according to requirements.